# how to set value in div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the value of div which I get from local storage from the previous input form.
I tried to get the value through local storage by setItem & getItem, but it's not working.
Here is small part of my code that I tried.

```js
function submit() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById("prefix").value;
  const fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  const mname = document.getElementById("mname").value;
  const lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

  localStorage.setItem("prefix", prefix);
  localStorage.setItem("fname", fname);
  localStorage.setItem("mname", mname);
  localStorage.setItem("lname", lname);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row mx-auto">
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-3 brdr">
    <h4 class="d-inline">Name</h4>
    <p class="d-inline">* (same as ID proof)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-2 brdr">
    <input type="text" id="prefix" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="prefix">
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-3 brdr">
    <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="first name">
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-2 brdr">
    <input type="text" id="mname" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="middle name">
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="last name">
  </div>
</div><br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="submit();">
</div>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const o_prefix = localStorage.getItem("prefix", prefix);
  const o_fname = localStorage.getItem("fname", fname);
  const o_mname = localStorage.getItem("mname", mname);
  const o_lname = localStorage.getItem("lname", lname);

  document.getElementById('o-prefix').innerHTML = o_prefix;
  document.getElementById('o-fname').innerHTML = o_fname;
  document.getElementById('o-mname').innerHTML = o_mname;
  document.getElementById('o-lname').innerHTML = o_lname;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row mx-auto">
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-3 brdr">
    <h4 class="d-inline">Name</h4>
    <p class="d-inline">* (same as ID proof)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-2 brdr" id="o-prefix"></div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-3 brdr" id="o-fname"></div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-end-0 col-sm-2 brdr" id="o-mname"></div>
  <div class="border border-dark col-sm-2" id="o-lname"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the actual localStorage ? does that value save there ? also, when you get the item you just have to specify it's name

Comment: @Mihai yes value saved in actual local storage

Answer (score 1):

you made a mistake with localStorage.getItem

here is examples in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

Comment: It works even if you write the way he did https://jsfiddle.net/25970aqe/ even though I agree it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly instead of storing different values store it in object like and you need to `stringfy` before saving it in `localStorage`.

**Saving in Local Storage**

```js
const prefix = document.getElementById("prefix").value;
const fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
const mname = document.getElementById("mname").value;
const lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringfy({
  prefix: prefix.value,
  fname: fname.value,
  mname: mname.value,
  lname: lname.value
}))
```

**Getting Data from Local Storage**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

  document.getElementById('o-prefix').innerText = userData.prefix;
  document.getElementById('o-fname').innerText = userData.fname;
  document.getElementById('o-mname').innerText = userData.mname;
  document.getElementById('o-lname').innerText = userData.lname;
})
```